# Почему Servlet имеет такое название?

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet, терминология

Почему "Servlet" имеет такое название? От куда пошло это название? От чего оно происходт?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/servlet) слово **Servlet** образовано из слов **server** +‎ **applet**, где последнее, согласно той же [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/applet#English) образовано из **app** ([сокращение](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/app#English) от **Application**) с приставкой **let**, [обозначающей малый размер](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-let#English)

В итоге, получается, должно обозначать **Маленькая серверная программа**

Comment: Наверно самый популярный пример про let -- Pig (свинья) и Piglet (Пятачок из Винни-Пуха).